# How can i console form data in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

How can i console form data in nativescript

```
<TextField hint="Username or Email" [text]='name' secure="false" returnKeyType="done" (returnPress)="onReturnPress($event)" autocorrect="false" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)" class="input input-border m-b-20"></TextField>
```

Comment: What you mean by form data here?

Answer (score 0):

since your question is not clear, i have done a playground sample look here. if you have further question update in playground i'll try to solve it.

https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.33733217.1511669966.1576233431-149906011.1576233431&template=play-js&id=VqOyyl